# Configuring startup files (robot_upstart)

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, husky, startup, robot-upstart

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys. We have just received a husky uvg at my lab and I am humbly trying to step out of the simulating world and set up the platform.

I would like to test some of the nodes I developed in simulation and make them run at start-up in the backround along with the standard startup husky nodes.

In the user manual, clearpath suggests to simply copy the custom launch file in the `/etc/ros/kinetic/husky-core.d` folder where the standard husky launch files are located (state publiser, localization etc)

While this works and the nodes do appear after boot (i checked it in my remote) it someshow doesn't feel like a robust technique. So after reading a little on the `robot_upstart` command and ubuntu's `service` and `systemctl` commands I believe that the best way to do what I want would be either to

1. create a new system service containing all the custom launch files to be launched at system boot or
2. create a new system service for each launch file.

I am closing towards the first. Should I proceed and do that or is there something that I have missintepreted that could cause a problem?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349462/configuring-startup-files-(robot_upstart)./) by [smarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/51434/smarn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 54 on 2020-04-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like it is sufficient to just copy any .launch file that is to be called during start-up in the `/etc/ros/kinetic/ros.d`
directory (eventually in my case it is not `husky-core.d` but `ros.d`) so i'm closing this one.

---

Originally posted by [smarn](https://answers.ros.org/users/51434/smarn/) with karma: 54 on 2020-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0